# iPad 2 update to iOS7

Tags: ipad, ios

I have and **iPad 2** with **5.1.1** installed. I didn't update to iOS 6 because I didn't want Apple Maps and have my VLC app deleted. Now since the majority of the apps don't get any updates I thought of updating to iOS 6 (thanks to Google releasing the maps as stand-alone), but that(thanks to Apple offering update to **only** iOS 7 and nothing in between) is not possible anymore.

My question is - is it worth it, for iPad 2, to download the iOS 7 update? The system now(5.1.1) is still very smooth, the only thing I miss are some updates to few apps and an update for the WebKit(browsers are constantly crashing when some websites have really rich JavaScript features...).

Comment: Every answer to every question is an opinion. It depends which facts are the basis for its formulation. One of the answers included link to a specific benchmarks comparing the performance of iOS 7 on iPad 2. Accepted answer pointed out facts about inability to downgrade after updating to iOS 7, which I hadn't known before. I don't see a reason for this question to be "on hold".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you're too late indeed to get iOS 6 on your iPad 2 since Apple doesn't support downgrading iOS7 to iOS6 **anymore**. This **was** possible when iOS7 came out, and that's why I'm pointing it out here.

As tried myself, I've updated an iPad 2 to iOS7 but decided to downgrade it to iOS6 as everything started to work slower - iOS7 on an iPhone 4 doesn't work very well either.

I'm glad it's back to iOS6, unfortunately for you there is nothing you can do now about it. If you jailbreak your device, you could upgrade it and downgrade with SHSH-blobs if you're not satisfied. There are guides around on how to do this.

> My question is - is it worth it, for iPad 2, to download the iOS 7
>   update? The system now(5.1.1) is still very smooth, the only thing I
>   miss are some updates to few apps and an update for the
>   WebKit(browsers are constantly crashing when some websites have really
>   rich JavaScript features...).

In short: No, it's not worth upgrading your iPad 2 to iOS7 as everything will work much **slower**. You could upgrade to iOS7, and if that isn't satisfying you you can always **downgrade** to iOS5 because you have that currently on your device using the **SHSH-blobs**.

Comment: I believe you misunderstood my question - the very first sentecnce says *I have an iPad 2 with 5.1.1 installed*. I didn't ask whether or not it is possible to downgrade from 7 to 6. Rather whether or not it is worth it to go from 5 to 7.

Comment: I've updated the answer. I was just pointing out it **was** possible to upgrade to iOS7 when it came out, and downgrade to iOS6 afterwards. But Apple removed that again.

Comment: @Michal Thanks for your reaction, tbh: I wouldn't do it.

Answer (score 1):

Have a read of [this article](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2013/09/dont-let-me-down-apple-ios-7-on-the-ipad-2/) , which conducts an analysis of iOS 7 on iPad 2, and see what you think. As noted in the link, enabling bold text will make a difference in iOS 7 on a non-retina display.